# Does a spin around axis not passing through COM ever stop?

Tags: angular-momentum

Suppose the rod is in space and I apply equal but opposite forces at both ends *momentarily*. The rod starts spinning around COM and I believe it should keep spinning forever because the COM is not accelerating and angular momentum has to be conserved. No issues in this case.

[image]

Next suppose I move the axis of rotation away from the COM, say, to 1/3rd from one end by pinning it,; then apply equal but opposite force at both ends *momentarily*. What happens now ? Would the rod keep spinning forever ? If yes, wouldn't this mean that the COM is accelerating ? If no, wouldn't this mean that the angular momentum is not conserved ?

Comment: How are you going to move the axis of rotation? That might answer your question. Also, remember Newton's first law.

Comment: @AaronStevens you've been my life saver today! ty again :) I think I can just nail the rod  1/3rd away from one end and give a little momentary torque so that it starts spinning ?

Comment: http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age11-14/Mechanics/Statics/text/Centre_of_gravity/images/2.png

Comment: I'm asking because I've been told that COM cannot accelerate when $F_{net}$ is $0$. I think my question boils down to this : Would an object that is spinning about a non COM axis ever stop ? @AaronStevens

Comment: If there are no forces after you release then there is no acceleration.

Comment: But COM does accelerate as it moves in a circle around the nail, right ?

Comment: Its speed doesn't change, but surely its direction continuously changes..

Comment: https://ubisafe.org/images/acceleration-vector-horizontal.png

Comment: As soon as you release the constraint it will rotate about the COM

Comment: My previous comment assumes the pin is removed when the forces stop as well.

Comment: So, is the hinge frictionless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an object rotate about a point not at the center of mass, you need a joint (hinge) at that location that would supply the necessary forces to accelerate the center of mass (since it is now orbiting a point).

The body is going to move forever because reaction forces do not produce work (they don't add or remove power). The reaction force is either applied through a point that doesn't move (hinge point), or along a direction perpendicular to motion (sliding joint) in general.

Again, the COM *does* accelerate, but the force needed to do so does not affect the conservation of energy or momentum.